# Infinite loop using useEffect, useState and useSWR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```js
const [ useStateVar, setUseStateVar ] = useState({})
const { data } = useSWR("demo/data", fetcher, {refreshInterval: 1000})

useEffect(() => {setUseStateVar(useStatevar+1)}, [data])
```

I believe the above code runs like this:
When the data first update at a 1s frequent, it triggers the `useEffect()` to update `useStateVar` using `setUseStateVar`, once the `useStatevar` is updated, the `data` update again, when the `data` updated, it triggers the `useEffect()`, so it created an infinite loop to the browser to update the value and hit the maximum.

I aim to get the updated data using `useSWR()` and update some variables, and reload the component while `data` is updated.

How can I achieve it without creating an infinite loop?

Comment: You could maybe consider storing the values that you want to update base on the `data` in a `ref` (using the `useRef` hook) instead of storing them in a separate state (with the `useState` hook) and then force a re-render to update them on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the infinite loop in your code, you can use the `useRef` hook to keep track of the previous value of the data fetched by `useSWR`. This way, you can compare the current data with the previous value and conditionally update the `useStateVar` only when the data changes. Here's how you can achieve it:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr';

const Component = () => {
  const [useStateVar, setUseStateVar] = useState({});
  const { data } = useSWR("demo/data", fetcher, { refreshInterval: 1000 });

  // Create a ref to keep track of the previous data value
  const prevDataRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if prevDataRef.current exists and if the data has changed
    if (prevDataRef.current && data !== prevDataRef.current) {
      // Update the useStateVar only when the data changes
      setUseStateVar(prevState => {
        // Modify the state based on the new data
        // For example, you can merge the new data with the previous state
        return { ...prevState, ...data };
      });
    }

    // Update the prevDataRef with the current data value for the next comparison
    prevDataRef.current = data;
  }, [data]);

  // Rest of your component code
  return (
    // JSX elements
  );
}
```

the `useRef` hook is to create prevDataRef, which holds the previous value of data. Inside the `useEffect` hook, we check if the `prevDataRef.current` exists (i.e., it is not null or undefined) and if the current data value is different from the previous one.

If there's a change in the data, we update the `useStateVar` state by merging the new data with the previous state (you can modify this part based on your specific use case).

comparing the current and previous data values, we ensure that the `useStateVar` state is only updated when there's a genuine change in the data fetched by `useSWR`, avoiding the infinite loop issue.

Comment: You saved my life with a very great solution, thank you Syed!